# OWL Equivalent Classes as complement of Sibling SubClass

Tags: owl, protege, inference, reasoner

I have the following made up example class hierarchy for clearing my doubt.

[image: Example Class Hierarchy]

The class of `Dog` and `Human` are subclasses of `Animal`. Also present is the class `Leash`.

I have modelled the Dog class as a Defined Class with a property restriction on an object property `wearsLeash` as shown.

[image]

I have modelled the Human class as the complement of the Dog class as shown

[image]

I have three individuals for these classes as below. `Leo` is supposed to be the `Dog` and `David` the `Human`

[image]

I have asserted that `Leo wearsLeash RedLeash` as shown.

[image]

On running the built-in reasoner, `Leo` gets `classified` as a `Dog` but `David` doesn't get classified as a `Human`. My questions is why is it that `David` not inferred as an individual of `Human` as the class of animals that are not dogs? Is it due to the Open world assumption ? What other ways do I have to automatically infer `David` as `Human` using this logic?

Thanks!

EDIT: OWL file

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107#wearsLeash
:wearsLeash rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107#Animal
:Animal rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107#Dog
:Dog rdf:type owl:Class ;
     owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Animal
                                                [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                  owl:onProperty :wearsLeash ;
                                                  owl:someValuesFrom :Leash
                                                ]
                                              ) ;
                           rdf:type owl:Class
                         ] ;
     rdfs:subClassOf :Animal ;
     owl:disjointWith :Human .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107#Human
:Human rdf:type owl:Class ;
       owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Animal
                                                  [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                                                    owl:complementOf :Dog
                                                  ]
                                                ) ;
                             rdf:type owl:Class
                           ] .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107#Leash
:Leash rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107#David
:David rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                :Animal .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107#Leo
:Leo rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
              :Animal ;
     :wearsLeash :RedLeash .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/university/untitled-ontology-107#RedLeash
:RedLeash rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                   :Leash .


#################################################################
#    General axioms
#################################################################

[ rdf:type owl:AllDifferent ;
  owl:distinctMembers ( :David
                        :Leo
                      )
] .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: Please provide the complete .owl for your ontology.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse I have edited it for the ontology, thanks

Comment: Thanks! I will have a quick look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ontology `Human` is defined as the intersection of `Animal` and the complement of `Dog`, which, for the purpose of classifying `Human` instances, is equivalent to defining `Animal` as the disjoint union of `Dog` and `Human`.

This means that anything that is defined as being an `Animal` will be either a `Dog` or a `Human`; an instance can be classified as a `Dog` if it is known to wear a leash.

The problem here is that `David` is not known to wear a leash and is not known *not* to wear a leash; Open World Assumption means that the reasoner cannot choose either possibility and cannot, therefore decide whether `David` is a `Dog` or a `Human`. To obtain what you want it's necessary to add more information to the ontology, such as that `David` belongs to a class that is outside the domain of `wearsLeash`.